# How to weave C# code to intercept call to constructors ? Maybe a custom preprocessor or Roslyn

Tags: c#, preprocessor, metaprogramming, aop, roslyn

Is there any solution similar to [PostSharp] - [Infuse - A Precompiler for C#] that let me modify code at compile time ?

The below is a pseudo code.

```
[InterceptCallToConstructors]
void Method1(){
    Person Eric = new Person("Eric Bush");
}


InterceptCallToConstructors(ConstructorMethodArgs args){
    if(args.Type == typeof(Person))
        if(PersonInstances++ > 10 ) args.ReturnValue = null;
}
```

In this example we see the Eric should not contain a new Person class if more than 10 Person are created.

After some research I found two solution PostSharp and Infuse.
With Infuse it's very complicated and hard to detect how many instance of Person are made how ever with PostSharp it's one line code to detect.

I have tried to go AOP with PostSharp but PostSharp currently doesn't support to intercept Call To Constructor Aspect.
As far as I read Roslyn doesn't support to modify code at compile time.

Comment: Are you trying to insert the "if (args..." check, into "Method1" programatically? (This is a kind of aspect oriented programming)?

Comment: @IraBaxter Yes it must be done programitically!

Comment: If you are running PostSharp, you are modifying the code *after* compilation. What do you mean, "at compiletime"?  you want changes to the source code before compilation?

Comment: @IraBaxter You are right. It's not important if it's after compilation or in compile time. I'll edit question

Comment: Like Ira Baxter [said above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27333277#comment43128775_27333277), AOP with PostSharp is a post-compilation transformation: it rewrites the compiled IL code, and you could do the same with libraries such as [CCI](https://ccimetadata.codeplex.com/). If you actually want to change the working of the compiler, you might be interested in the [Boo language/compiler](http://boo.codehaus.org/) (though I do not know whether it would be possible to do with Boo's extensible compiler architecture what you want to do here).

Comment: If I saw this in my codebase, I'd be terribly annoyed at the obfuscation. Although it's not an answer to your question, consider just explicitly calling a static factory method `CreatePerson` that handles this logic, rather than (in effect) defining your own language that just happens to look a lot like C#. Of course, if that is actually exactly your goal, it's fine.

Comment: And what, exactly, would the resulting code look like?  (Seems you want to modify the constructor call site, rather than the constructor body).  Do I have that right?  Could you revise your question to show the code that achieves the exact effect you want the transformation to do?

Answer (score 1):

This would be a "custom preprocessor" answer, that modifies the source code to achieve OP's effect.

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) with its [C# Front End](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CSharpFrontEnd.html) can do this.

DMS provides for source to source transformations, with the transformations coded as

```
if you see *this*, replace it by *that*
```

This is written in the form:

```
rule xxx pattern_parameters
    this_pattern
    ->  that_pattern ;
```

The "->" is pronounced "replace by: :-}

DMS operates on ASTs, so includes a parsing step (text to ASTs), a tree transformation step, and a prettyprinting step that produces the final answer (ASTs to text).

OP's seems to want to modify the constructor call site (he can't modify the constructor; there's no way to get it to return "null").  To accomplish OP's, task, he would provide DMS the following source-to-source transformation specification:

```
       default domain CSharp~v5;  -- says we are working with C# syntax (and need the C# front end)

       rule intercept_constructor(c: IDENTIFIER, a:arguments): expression
           "  new \c (\a) "
       ->  "  \c.PersonInstances==10?null:(PersonInstances++,new \c (\a)) "
           if c == "Person";  -- one might want to force c to be on some qualified path
```

What the rule does is find matching constructor call syntax of arbitrary form, and replace it by a conditional expression that check's OP's precondition, returning null if there are too many Person instances (we fix a bug in OP's spec here; he appears to increment the count whether new Person instance is created or not, surely not his intention).  We have to qualify the PersonInstance's location; it can't just be floating around in the ether. In this example I'm proposing it is a static member of the class.

The details:  each rule has a name ("intercept_constructor", stolen from OP).  It refers to a syntactic category ("expression") with syntactic shape "new \c (\a)", forcing it to match only constructor calls that are expressions.  The quotes in the rule are *meta-quotes*; they distinguish the syntax of the rule language from the syntax of the targeted language (C# in this case).   The backslashes are meta-escapes;  \c in meta-quotes is the same think in the rule as c outside the meta-quotes, similarly for \a.

In a really big system there may be several Person classes.  We want to make sure we get right one; one might need to qualify the referenced class as being a specific by by providing a path.   OP hints at this with the annotation.   If one wanted to check that an annotation existed on the containing method, one would need custom special predicate to ask for that.  DMS provides complete facilities for coding such a predicate, including complete access the the AST, so the predicate can climb up or down in its search for a matching annotation.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't count how many instance of Persons are made and I really need to return null.

Comment: Oops, I missed a detail; in fact several silly things wrong in rule; must have been late night when I posted this answer.  I fixed the silly things and revised the pattern to increment the count if it was not too big. The original, and this version, both return null if the count is too big. *Please* show in your question the code you expect to get.

Comment: My exact goal is to intercept call to constructor and handle return value, not only handle return but a full control over constructor method just like I'm inside constructor method. Postsharp MethodInterception exactly does what I want but unfortunately it supports all methos except call to constructor!

Comment: I understand your goal.  You are resisting multiple requests to show exactly the code you expect of the final result.  I claim my rule above does that, until you can show specifically how it wrong.

Comment: Does it count instances if they are made inside a loop ? Is your suggested toolkit free or trial ?

Comment: It does what you appear to ask:  anyplace there is a new Person(...) call, you get code to check the count and conditionally call new Person.  "if you see *this*, replace it by *that*" everywhere in the code base.  If you put those calls inside a loop, it will count instances that occur inside the loop. *Look* at the code it inserts.

Comment: DMS is a commercial product.  If you want to discuss trials that should be offline.  My contact information easily found in my bio.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on top of the KRuntime (-> ASP.NET 5) you can hook into the compilation by implementing the [ICompileModule assembly neutral interface](https://github.com/aspnet/KRuntime/blob/75db9417741fa4f3b70c0db12bed80063e35163e/src/Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Roslyn/Services/ICompileModule.cs).

I'd recommend loooking at:

- the aop [example in the repo](https://github.com/aspnet/KRuntime/blob/6c16c5b2feb074baa571749bb4dec71f9af701ae/samples/HelloWorld/compiler/preprocess/HelloMetaProgramming.cs)
- [this nice writeup](http://www.strathweb.com/2014/12/razor-views-pre-compilation-asp-net-5-mvc-6/)